# gradle test command fails outofmemory issue in Gradle 8

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit5, java-11

JUnit5 unit test case in Java11 and when I am running the gradle test for testing the entire Junit test cases I am getting OutOfMemoryError exception. Individual test classes are executing fine without any issue. It looks like heap memory issue in Java.

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.14'

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, Gradle runs all test classes parallelly. Java11 default heap memory size is 256MB. This is not enough to run all the test classes parallelly. This causes “Java Out of Memory ” error. We can fix this by increasing heap memory in test run by adding the below code. If test case are more, we need to increase heap size more that what I have given.

We won't face this issue when we upgrade to JAVA17. Because , java17 will take 1/4 of the physical memory as heap memory

dependencies.gradle

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.14'
    test {
          minHeapSize = "256m" // initial heap size
          maxHeapSize = "1024m" // maximum heap size
          useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```